# Checkboxes arent working in chrome (only on my site)

Tags: html, browser, checkbox

Im currently developing this site so none of the content on there is actually 'real' content as such.

If you look at the top left you'll see "aegaegaegaeg" Next to that on the left side should be a checkbox with no styling?...

It works in every other browser other than chrome and i've tested the checkbox code in a simple html file and it works, no idea to why its doing this? ive tried restarting, changing my windows theme etc nothing.

Site: http://www.tfbox.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the theme reset CSS file is causing this:
http://tfbox.com/wp-content/themes/tfbox-beta/css/reset.css

```
input { -webkit-appearance:none; }
```

comment it and you'll be just fine:

```
/*input { -webkit-appearance:none; }*/
```

Comment: God... What an amateur mistake that was on my part, I should have known haha. Thankyou.